# Using Angular 10 with BsDatepickerConfig and ngModel - Store date, not time

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngmodel

I'm using ngx-bootstrap's BsDatepicker and BsDatepickerConfig to capture a date (Student DOB) and write it to my backend using ngModel. I just want to store YYYY-MM-DD; however, the value is being stored as a date/time stamp, example: 1981-02-04T06:00:00.000Z. How can I just capture YYYY-MM-DD?

snippet from create-student.component.ts:

```
  bsValue = new Date();
  datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  constructor(private studentService: StudentService,
             private router: Router) { 

    this.datePickerConfig = Object.assign({}, { showWeekNumbers: false,
                                                dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'})  ;
  }

  saveStudent() {
    this.studentService.createStudent(this.student).subscribe( data => {
      this.goToStudentList();
    },
    error => console.log(error));
  }
```

snippet from create-student.component.html:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="dob">DOB</label>
            <input type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                bsDatepicker 
                [bsValue]="bsValue"
                [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" 
                [(ngModel)]="student.dob" 
                autocomplete="off"
                name="dob"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: it is not clear from the code provided where the data is sent to your backend for saving. Can you not just convert the date to string format using something like date-fns format for formatting dates before sending it to your backend? virtually everycode codebase should have a good date library such a date-fns (check npm trends for other alternatives)